# Ditherin in Python

Tags: python-3.4, dithering

I'm writing a simple script for Dithering in python 3.4 using pygame and numpy. I already did it in processing without problems but I'm getting bad results with python.

This is my script in Python and this are the results I'm getting

```
from pygame import display, surfarray, image
import pygame
from pygame.locals import Color
import numpy as np

factor = 3

pygame.init()
imagen = image.load("download.jpg") #Pygame Surface
imagen_pix = surfarray.array3d(imagen)
width, height = imagen.get_width(),imagen.get_height()
screen = display.set_mode((width*2,height))

for y in range(height-1):
    for x in range(width-1):
        oldR, oldG, oldB = imagen_pix[x][y]

        newR = round((factor-1)*oldR/255.0)*(255.0/(factor-1))
        newG = round((factor-1)*oldG/255.0)*(255.0/(factor-1))
        newB = round((factor-1)*oldB/255.0)*(255.0/(factor-1))

        imagen_pix[x][y] = (newR, newG, newB)

        errR = oldR-newR
        errG = oldG-newG
        errB = oldB-newB

        r, g, b = imagen_pix[x+1][y]
        r += errR*7.0/16.0
        g += errG*7.0/16.0
        b += errB*7.0/16.0
        imagen_pix[x][y] = (r, g, b)

        r, g, b = imagen_pix[x-1][y+1]
        r += errR * 3.0 / 16.0
        g += errG * 3.0 / 16.0
        b += errB * 3.0 / 16.0
        imagen_pix[x][y] = (r, g, b)

        r, g, b = imagen_pix[x][y+1]
        r += errR * 5.0 / 16.0
        g += errG * 5.0 / 16.0
        b += errB * 5.0 / 16.0
        imagen_pix[x][y] = (r, g, b)

        r, g, b = imagen_pix[x + 1][y+1]
        r += errR * 1.0 / 16.0
        g += errG * 1.0 / 16.0
        b += errB * 1.0 / 16.0
        imagen_pix[x][y] = (r, g, b)

imagenNueva = surfarray.make_surface(imagen_pix)

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.blit(imagen, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(imagenNueva, (width, 0))
    display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

[This is the result in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOUDs.png)

[This is the result in Processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrL9L.png)

Whats the problem with my python script?

Comment: Since `x` stays in `range(width-1)`, the line with `imagen_pix[x-1][y+1]` seems to cause a negative index. Should that be `x+1` perhaps? Also, you're reading from various locations, but always writing to `imagen_pix[x][y]`. Is that your intention? At a first glance that seems that only the final assignment to `imagen_pix[x][y]` would be used this way.

Comment: `imagen_pix[x-1][y+1]` is part of the algorith for Dithering. I changed to `range(1,width-1)` and `range(1,height-1)` to avoid the negative index but no luck. And yes, my intention is to read and update 5 times  `imagen_pix` in each iteration.